# LLVM cmake find_package throws a error that libedit is not found! How to fix it?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, llvm

I have a small project where I want to use the LLVM IR API. So I made a new cmake project on my wls (host machine is windows) installing the llvm-15 package. An starting to code a basic cmake file.

But following line produces a error in my cmake file:

```
find_package(LLVM 15 REQUIRED CONFIG)
```

It produces following error:

```
C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu --exec /bin/bash -c "export CMAKE_COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS=ON && export CLION_IDE=TRUE && export JETBRAINS_IDE=TRUE && cd /mnt/d/git/llvm-antlr4-starter/cmake-build-debug-wsl && /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G 'CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles' -S /mnt/d/git/llvm-antlr4-starter -B /mnt/d/git/llvm-antlr4-starter/cmake-build-debug-wsl"
-- Found LLVM 15.0.6
-- Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: /usr/lib/llvm-15/cmake
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:2255 (message):
  Policy CMP0114 is not set: ExternalProject step targets fully adopt their
  steps.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0114" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  ExternalProject target 'antlr4_runtime' would depend on the targets for
  step(s) 'build_static' under policy CMP0114, but this is being left out for
  compatibility since the policy is not set.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:149 (ExternalProject_Add_StepTargets)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:2255 (message):
  Policy CMP0114 is not set: ExternalProject step targets fully adopt their
  steps.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0114" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  ExternalProject target 'antlr4_runtime' would depend on the targets for
  step(s) 'build_shared' under policy CMP0114, but this is being left out for
  compatibility since the policy is not set.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:166 (ExternalProject_Add_StepTargets)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/lib/llvm-15/include
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at /usr/lib/llvm-15/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVMExports.cmake:1198 (set_target_properties):
  The link interface of target "LLVMLineEditor" contains:

    LibEdit::LibEdit

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/llvm-15/cmake/LLVMConfig.cmake:336 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.

[Finished]
```

I installed libediit and tried to include libedit manually but that doesn't produce just more errors that he cant find it.

Now I don't know how I can fix the code, reinstalling llvm-15 does not work too.
Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
Temporary fix is to use LLVM 12 instead of LLVM 15, but well obviously thats not a true solution. So hope someone has an idea to fix the problem

Comment: Did you install the `libedit-dev` package as well?

Comment: Yes, but that does not change anything. But the cmake files for libedit are missing. Installing from source does not create them too.

Comment: That `LibEdit::LibEdit` target is [defined here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/3676a86a4322e8c2b9c541f057b5d3704146b8f3/cmake/Modules/FindLibEdit.cmake). It just looks for histedit.h and libedit.so, which should have been installed by `libedit-dev`.

Comment: I don't understand how you can have `HAVE_LIBEDIT` set but not the target defined ... as a workaround you could run cmake with `-DLLVM_ENABLE_LIBEDIT=0`, but this is curious.

Comment: I did try to use -DLLVM_ENABLE_LIBEDIT=0 interrestingly cmake does not change his behaviour

Comment: Oh reinstalling libedit-dev with brew instead of apt fixed it. Not 100% sure why